# 'await' is not working in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

The code below gives me the following error:

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

```
async function getLastTransaction() 
{
    paymentsApi.listPayments(locationId, opts).then(function(transactions) 
    {
        if(transactions[transactions.length-1] === undefined)
            return; //no new transaction yet

        var last_transaction_id = transactions[transactions.length-1].id;
        var last_transaction_in_queue; 

        try {
            last_transaction_in_queue = JSON.parse(order_queue[0]).order_id;
        } catch (e) {
            last_transaction_in_queue = order_queue[0].order_id;
        }

        //check if latest transaction is the same as lastest transaction in queue
        if(last_transaction_id !== last_transaction_in_queue) {

            console.log(`new payment...`); 

            var obj = await createTransactionObject(transactions[transactions.length-1], () => {
                order_queue.unshift(obj);
                console.log('new added', order_queue);
            });
}
```

I don't understand the error since I'm using `await` for the same function `createTransactionObject()` but in another piece of code.

For example, in the following code, I don't get the error, and still, I'm using `await` before `createTransactionObject()`

```
async function populateQueue(transaction_list)  {
    for(var i = 0; i < transaction_list.length; i++) 
    {
        var transaction_json = await createTransactionObject(transaction_list[i], () => {});
        order_queue.unshift(transaction_json);
    } }
```

Comment: this function needs to be async: `function(transactions)`

Comment: Of course it is pointless to use `then()` when OP declares the function as `async`.

Comment: You might also want to look into arrow functions http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this

Answer (score 5):

You need to change this line:

```
paymentsApi.listPayments(locationId, opts).then(function(transactions)
```

to this:

```
paymentsApi.listPayments(locationId, opts).then(async (transactions) =>
```

The anonymous function you supply to .then needs to be asynced, because you're using await in it.

You could also replace the line with this (maybe even better):

```
const transactions = await paymentsApi.listPayments(locationId, opts);
```

Because the getLastTransaction function is asynced.

Comment: Or even better to `const transactions = await paymentsApi.listPayments(locationId, opts);` Lets use that `async` (assuming it is compatible).

Comment: @freakish Yeah, totally missed that, added to answer!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you get the error **not** because the `getLastTransaction` function is async **but** because the anonymous function `.then(function(transactions)` **is not async** and you use `await` inside of it. You can't do that.

Now note that simple redeclaring the function as `async function(transactions)` will be syntactically correct but will that work fine? What happens now is that `getLastTransaction` fires some async process in the background and **never** awaits the result. Is that what you want?

To fix that you have to ask yourself: what am I trying to achieve? Should `getLastTransaction` wait for whatever the inner function is doing? Then make use of that `async` declaration:

```
async function getLastTransaction() {
    const transactions = await paymentsApi.listPayments(locationId, opts);
    // Some other code here
    return xyz;
}
```

This is under the assumption that the `paymentsApi` is async/await compatible. If it is not then you have to play with manually creating and returning `Promise` objects (in which case `async` declaration won't help much).

Answer (score 0):

`paymentsApi.listPayments(locationId, opts).then(function(transactions)` should be
`paymentsApi.listPayments(locationId, opts).then(async function(transactions)` as `await` can only be used in an `asynchronous function`.

Better still, since you already have an `async` function at the top level, why don't you just `await` `paymentsApi.listPayments(locationId, opts)` instead of chaining it with a `then`?

```
async function getLastTransaction() {
    const transactions = await paymentsApi.listPayments(locationId, opts);
    // Do something with transactions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`await` keyword works when scope is having `async` keyword used, here `.then` accepts callback function that doesn't have `async`, so `await` becomes alien here.

Lets re-write your code in `async-await` style:

```
async function getLastTransaction() 
{
    // #1 this fixes to adopt the await style and fixes the problem
    const transactions = await paymentsApi.listPayments(locationId, opts);

    // your rest code goes here ...

    if(last_transaction_id !== last_transaction_in_queue) {
            //now do it like this, await will make sense now
            const obj = await createTransactionObject(transactions[transactions.length-1]);
            order_queue.unshift(obj);
    }
}
```